# Converting the form of an observable array and displaying in select list

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-3.0

I have an observable array as below..

```
var myObservableArray = ko.observableArray(["Bungle","George","Zippy"]);
```

I wish to copy the elements into another observable array but in the following format where type is always unknown..

```
var anotherObservableArray = ko.observableArray([
    { name: "Bungle", type: "Unknown" },
    { name: "George", type: "Unknown" },
    { name: "Zippy", type: "Unknown" }
]);
```

If the original myObservableArray changes, anotherObservableArray also needs to change.
Any help is sincerely appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: That's a lot of requirements there - could you edit your question to perhaps only ask one of them?  Have you got any code to create `anotherObservableArray` yet?  Does the second array need to update if the original `observableArray` updates?

Comment: @JamesThorpe Updated...

Comment: Is cloning the data required or you just need another property that would massage your data to a the desired `{name, type}` format?

Comment: @haim770 I need to copy it into a separate observable, If I did not need to change format I could have used ko.utils.arrayPushAll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a view model from original data and then use it ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kt0ov3t4/)):

```
var originalArray = ["Bungle","George","Zippy"];
function createItemModel(name) {
  var model = {
    name: ko.observable(name),
    type: ko.observable("Unknown"),
  }
  model.displayText = ko.computed(function() {
    return model.name() + '-' + model.type();
  });
  return model;
}
var myObservableArray = ko.observableArray(originalArray.map(createItemModel));

var viewModel = {
  myObservableArray: myObservableArray,
  selected: ko.observable()
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

And use this in the markup (from your second question):

```
<select data-bind="options: myObservableArray,
                   optionsText: 'displayText',
                   value: selected"></select>
```

#### Update 1

Updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kt0ov3t4/1/) with changing type for selected item.

Comment: in my case original array is also observable.., so just a small change https://jsfiddle.net/kt0ov3t4/2/

Comment: I hope you have no troubles with extra pair of brackets :) I can update my fiddle and post it as an answer of your third question, if you don't mind.

Comment: changing the selected().type should solve it.., If you answer it, I will mark it as answer..