# Changing values in observable arrays in knockout

Tags: knockout.js

This question is a continuation of [this..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34454247/showing-a-concatenated-string-from-multiple-values-of-observable-array/34454304#34454304)

I have an observable array as follows:

```
var myObservableArray = ko.observableArray([
    { name: "Bungle", type: "Unknown" },
    { name: "George", type: "Unknown" },
    { name: "Zippy", type: "Unknown" }
]);
```

I fill up a select list box using the below code:

```html
<select data-bind="options: myObservableArray,
                   optionsText: function(item) {
                       return item.name + '-' + item.type;
                   },optionsValue:'name',
                   value: selected"></select>
```

I need a method which can change the type of selected value to '`mytype`'
eg.. if `Bungle` is selected...  `{ name: "Bungle", type: "mytype" }`

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Comment: You can check my answer on your original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34453587/converting-the-form-of-an-observable-array-and-displaying-in-select-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kt0ov3t4/3/) illustrating changing of the selected object type via text input.

View model:

```
var viewModel = {
  myObservableArray: myObservableArray,
  selected: ko.observable()
};
```

And markup:

```
<!-- ko if: selected -->
<div>Type:</div>
<input data-bind="value: selected().type"/>
<!-- /ko -->
```